# Creating a table from another table and a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to be able to create a table from an existing table and a stored procedure (which returns a varchar by taking a parameter). What I want to do is something like

```
select a.column1, procedureResult.* 
into newtable 
from table a 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=(local)\SQL2008;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
 'EXEC myStoredProcedure') AS procedureResult
```

It seems like I am missing some steps for creating a table using an existing table and a stored procedure at the same time. Also, I am not sure where to provide the parameter for the stored procedure in the OPENROWSET.

I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: *"Also I am not sure where to provide the parameter for the stored procedure in the OPENROWSET"* You would have to pass it as a literal value `'EXEC MySP @Param = 7;'`

Answer (score 0):

Although it's more effort, this would be the best approach.

```
create table #TempTable
(
    [newtableid] [int] null
)

insert into #TempTable
exec myStoredProcedure

select a.column1, procedureResult.* 
into newtable 
from table a 
union all 
select *
from #TempTable as procedureResult
```